# Split a string which is already in list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
elements = local_browsers.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='small margin-top-xsmall margin-bottom-xsmall']")
elements = [obj.text.split('\n') for obj in elems]
return elems
```

expected_output:

```
['someuser','password','another']
```

but getting result as:

```
[['someuser','password','another']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a list within a list because the output of a list comprehension is a list, and the output of `str.split` is a list.  Putting `str.split` inside a list comprehension therefore gives you two lists.

If you can assume that the first element is the only element, then you can handle this by avoiding the list comprehension:

```
elems[0].text.split('\n')
```

If you want to flatten the results so that all of the lines in all of the elements appear in one list:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain(*(obj.text.split('\n') for obj in elems)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is difficult to pull off in a list comprehension. Instead, you can use a traditional for loop, and extend a list instead of building it as you go.

```
elements = local_browsers.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='small margin-top-xsmall margin-bottom-xsmall']")
elems = []
for obj in elements:
    elems += obj.text.split('\n')
return elems
```